# How to build a PHP/Node proxy to render external http images on https website?

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, https, proxy

I have a website running on `https`.
I have to load images from external server (external domain) which doesn't have https, but single `http` protocol.

**Is there's any way to handle proxy for `http` images via PHP or Node?** So I can render images like this:

```
<img src="https://domain.com/proxy?url=http://externaldomain.com/image.jpg" />
```

The idea is to avoid saving images on local, but only display them.

When I try to render `http` served images inside `https` domain, I get this console message:

> The page at https://domain.com/ displayed insecure content from http://externaldomain.com/image.jpg.

As well, my SSL (/https) lock icon inside address bar becomes grey.

Answer (score 6):

You can use node, which will just pipe the image instead of loading the whole image into memory before sending to the client (like `file_get_contents` would do in php).
Using request in this example for simplicity in [streaming](https://github.com/mikeal/request#streaming):

```
var https = require('https');
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');

var server = https.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

  if (queryData.url) {
    var x = request(queryData.url);
    req.pipe(x).pipe(res);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("No url");
  }
});

// Listen on port 443
server.listen(443);
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
    $p = "http://i.imgur.com/jB3xD75.jpg";
    $a = file_get_contents($p);
    echo $a;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first download them using php cURL library. If you don't want to store images on hard drive. You can add them as data URIs in the src attribute.