# Node.js express routes aren't catching some GETS even with wildcard

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver, url-routing

I'm making a web app that runs on a node express webserver.  I have the routes currently setup like this:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res){
    var url = req.originalUrl;

    if(url == '/'){
        res.render('index.html');
    } else {
        console.log("**USING * HANDLER");
        var string = url.substr(1, url.length);
        res.render(string);
    }

});
```

I have it setup that way cause it takes care of at least 15 links from the `index.html` file in one pass.

Now below that, I also have:

```
app.get('/proxy*', function (req, res) {
    console.log('**USING /proxy HANDLER');
    //return proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, proxyOptions);
});
```

That's because my server makes some requests like:

`GET /proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fa.tile.cloudmade.com%2FBC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707%2F997%2F256%2F0%2F0%2F0.png`

I need those requests to be handled separately.  The problem is it seems like a lot of stuff gets by without any printing.  Here's a list of some of the GETS:

```
**USING * HANDLER
GET / 304 8ms
**USING * HANDLER
GET /leaflet.html 304 5ms
GET /leaflet/dist/leaflet.js 304 1ms
GET /js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js 304 1ms
GET /js/osgjs/osg-debug-0.0.7.js 304 2ms
GET /js/osgjs/osg-extras.js 304 3ms
GET /js/osgearth/FunctionLocation.js 304 3ms
GET /js/osgearth/osgearth.js 304 4ms
GET /js/osgearth/ShaderFactory.js 304 2ms
GET /js/osgearth/VirtualProgram.js 304 1ms
GET /js/osgearth/Extent.js 304 2ms
GET /js/osgearth/EllipsoidModel.js 304 1ms
GET /js/osgearth/Profile.js 304 2ms
GET /js/osgearth/GeodeticProfile.js 304 2ms
GET /js/osgearth/MercatorProfile.js 304 3ms
GET /js/osgearth/TileKey.js 304 3ms
GET /js/osgearth/ImageLayer.js 304 2ms
GET /js/osgearth/HeightField.js 304 2ms
GET /js/osgearth/ElevationLayer.js 304 3ms
```

And that's it.  It prints `USING * HANDLER` for the GETS I actually manually make myself.  So when I go to the server URL for `/`, and when I then click on the link for `leaflet.html`  After that, all the GETS made by the server return successfully but it never prints.  It also never prints for the proxy route.  What gives? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using `connect/static` as middleware?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The only modules I'm using currently are ``express``, ``http``, ``path``, and ``http-proxy``.  I really don't know alot about proxies.  Basically, the back-end of this web app wasn't made by me.  It normally uses a proxy.php file that just uses curl to get the contents and echoes them, to avoid cross domain security issues.  I want to avoid using php and try to use a proxy compatible with node.  I've found this, but I can't get this working either. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085460/how-to-build-a-php-node-proxy-to-render-external-http-images-on-https-website

Comment: Ok, the 304's looked like something similar to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));` would be configured.

Comment: Sorry, I do actually have a line similar to that: ``app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));``

Comment: Try commenting that line out, as far as I remember, if the file exists in the file system, `static` serves it without invoking any route.

Comment: Hey thanks that worked! Now how would I get it to serve all the ``js``, ``css``, ``png`` files and other? Basically all the static files that aren't ``html``? Before you can see I was doing ``res.render``, but now it's throwing errors that it can't find module js, or module png and so on

Comment: Well, that's what it does with the config you had, automatically serves any static file that exists, and calls your handler if it doesn't. I'm not sure what the original config did that you don't want, calling your handler for static files is probably not very useful. If you just remove the `leaflet.html` file, it should invoke your route for it instead of trying to serve it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34072/discussion-between-krb686-and-joachim-isaksson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick recap how this was solved;

It turns out that `express.static` was configured to have priority to serve files that existed in the file system before any routes were called.

Removing the static files that weren't to be served (proxy.php in this case) from the file system allowed the route handler to be called as intended instead of static serving the *content* of proxy.php.